# Como persistir o estado de uma fila de pedidos?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, estrutura-de-dados

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação C# que necessita de uma fila de itens do tipo `Pedido`. Basicamente sempre que um novo pedido é criado ele é colocado na fila e a aplicação mostra os pedidos na ordem sequencial que devem ser entregues. Quando um pedido é finalizado ele sai da fila.

Por enquanto o que estou fazendo é basicamente manter uma propriedade `enum` status na classe pedido que quando o pedido é criado tem valor `StatusPedido.Enviado` e quando o pedido é entregue tem valor `StatusPedido.Entregue`. A fila, portanto, só inclui itens no estado enviado.

Pra persistir isso, a principio não é dificil. Minha primeira ideia foi criar uma propriedade `DataModificacao` nos pedidos e então ordenar os pedidos pela data de modificação lembrando que filas são "first in first out". Dessa forma, a aplicação le os pedidos na base de dados, ordena e monta a fila.

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é o seguinte: existe um requisito dos usuários serem capazes de reordenar a fila. Isso ocorre porque certas vezes um pedido que pode ser entregue mais rápido pode ser adiantado e passado na frente de outros.

Fazer isso no código é facil. Basicamente é so trocar referências e tudo funciona. Mas e pra persistir isso? Só data de modificação não resolve mais, porque quando carrega-se os pedidos da base de dados não vai ter informação de quais foram adiantados. Pensei em uma nova propriedade que tem o ID do pedido que deve vir em seguida, e uma propriedade contendo uma referência para o próximo pedido mas não sei se é uma boa abordagem, porque isso parece mais um detalhe de implementação de persistência do que algo que faz parte do domínio mesmo.

Além disso, um pedido quando está fora da fila (ou antes de ser integrado a fila, ou depois de ser entregue) já não tem mais esse próximo, portanto o próximo pedido não parece uma propriedade da classe `Pedido` mesmo já que ela só faz sentido em certos casos.

Como eu posso fazer pra persistir esse tipo de coisa: uma fila que pode ser reordenada e que precisa ter sua ordenação persistida?

Answer (score 4):

## Abordagem 1: Prioridade

Uma abordagem pra resolver isso seria colocar uma coluna `Prioridade`, que é um enumerável. Por exemplo:

```
public enum Prioridade
{
    Minima,
    Baixa,
    Media,
    Alta,
    Maxima
}
```

O padrão seria `Minima`. Repare que a ordem do `enum` é proposital. `Maxima` receberá o maior valor inteiro dentro todos, e `Minima` o menor.

Assim a ordenação seria feita primeiro pela prioridade, depois pela data de modificação.

## Abordagem 2: Data de Ordem

Agora, se é realmente necessário uma ordem absoluta, o melhor é usar um `DateTime` com a data de ordem. Ao incluir o registro, `DataOrdem` é igual à `DataModificacao`.

A seguir, implemente um método que mude a ordem em tela. Para isso, coloque no seu *Model* uma `property` chamada `Ordem`, não mapeada em banco:

```
[NotMapped]
public int Ordem { get; set; }
```

Atribua valores para a ordem de cada elemento (1, 2, 3, 4...), permita ao usuário trocar a ordem em tela e ao persistir, faça `DataOrdem` receber `DateTime.Now`.

Assim, o primeiro elemento inserido será o primeiro da lista, pois tem a menor `DataOrdem`. Os demais estarão sensivelmente atrás (alguns milissegundos), o que garantirá a reordenação absoluta.

Comment: +1 pela o padrão por fila. Para complementar eu recomendo o [Priority Queue Pattern](link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589794.aspx) 
No entanto, eu não usaria a abordagem por data. Não vejo justificativa.

Comment: É quase um preciosismo a segunda, mas é bom saber que existe.

Comment: Ambientes extremos como bolsa de valores talvez!! kkk

Comment: Sim, ou outras aplicações que exijam precisão em milissegundos.

Answer (score 4):

Realmente, na minha opnião, o atributo ordem não faz parte de uma classe `Pedido`.
A melhor modelagem seria criar uma classe `ItemFila`. Veja uma proposta a seguir.

### Sugestão de implementação

```
class Fila{
    IList<ItemFila> Itens {get;set}
}

class ItemFila {
    public Pedido Pedido{get;set;}
    public int Posicao {get;set}
}

class Pedido {
    public DateTime CriadoEm {get;set}
    public StatusPedido Status {get;set;}
    // Dados do pedido
}
```

Nessa caso, essas classe representariam a mesma estrutura no banco de dados, assim, todas vez que você quiser
obter a fila, basta apenas carregar o objeto Fila.

### Ordenação

Sempre que for obter os ItemFila para compor a fila, você pode utilizar o `select` a seguir:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    ItemFila
ORDER BY 
    Posicao
ASC
```

Assim, você sempre terá a fila na ordem estabelecida no banco de dados (estou considerando que você está usando um banco de dados relacional).

### Atualização de posição

Suponha a sua fila tem 3 pedidos, e você precisa pegar o último e colocar em primeiro lugar. O que você deve fazer é somar o valor da posição atual em todos os item dessa fila, desde que esses item tenham o valor de posição menor que a posição atual.
Utilizando SQL ficaria assim:

```
DECLARE @current AS INT;
SELECT @current = Posicao FROM ItemFila WHERE Id = 123456;

UPDATE
    ItemFila
SET
    Posicao = Posicao + @current
WHERE
    Fila_ID = 123
    AND Posicao < @current;
```

***Edit***
É necessário incremementar os itens que vem a seguir também. Veja o código a seguir:

```
UPDATE
    ItemFila
SET
    Posicao = Posicao + @current
WHERE
    Fila_ID = 123
    AND Posicao > @current;
```

Comment: +1 pela resposta simples e detalhamento da solução.. faltou só uma tradução para o msql #joke :)